# Get name of last run program in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I trap errors using the trap command, and I would like to be able to print the name of the last command (the one that failed)

```
#!/bin/bash
function error
{
   # echo program name
}
trap error ERR
 # Some commands ...
/bin/false foo # For testing
```

I'm not sure what to put in the `error` function. I tried `echo $_` but that only works if the command has no arguments. I also tried with `!!` but that gives me "!!: command not found". At an interactive prompt (also bash) I get:

```
$ /bin/false foo
$ !!
/bin/false foo
```

which seems to be pretty much what I want. Why the difference?
What is the easiest way to get the name of the previous command inside a script?

Comment: History features are by default enabled only in interactive shells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `echo $BASH_COMMAND` in your trap function.

From `man bash`:

> BASH_COMMAND
>                 The  command  currently  being executed or about to be executed,
>                 unless the shell is executing a command as the result of a trap,
>                 in  which  case  it  is the command executing at the time of the
>                 trap.

Comment: echo $BASH_COMMAND outputs echo $BASH_COMMAND

Comment: @Rick: Yes, that's true on its own. My answer says to put that command in your trap function. If you do that then the command that triggers the trap will be output. This is spelled out in the section of the Bash man page I quoted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
set -o history
```

to quote bash manual page:

When  the  *-o history* option to the set builtin is enabled, the shell provides access to the command history, the list of commands previously typed.  The value of the HISTSIZE variable is used
   as the number of commands to save in a history list.  The text of the last HISTSIZE commands (default 500) is saved.  The shell stores each command in the history list prior to  parameter  and
   variable expansion (see EXPANSION above) but after history expansion is performed, subject to the values of the shell variables HISTIGNORE and HISTCONTROL.

In general, read the HISTORY and HISTORY EXPANSION sections in bash man page.