# SHELL general function for action state

Tags: bash

How to make a code bellow as a general function to be used entire script in bash:

```
if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then 
    echo "success " >> $log
else echo "failed" >> $log
fi
```

Comment: You mean to execute this automatically after every command?

Comment: Related and very useful: [What is the best way to write a wrapper function that runs commands and logs their exit code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/372120/1983854)

Answer (score 2):

You might write a wrapper for command execution:

```
function exec_cmd {
    $@
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then 
        echo "success " >> $log
    else 
        echo "failed" >> $log
    fi
}
```

And then execute commands in your script using the function:

```
exec_cmd command1 arg1 arg2 ...
exec_cmd command2 arg1 arg2 ...
...
```

Comment: as @fedorqui linked, `"$@"` would make life a lot easier here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wrap the original calls you could use an explicit call, like the following

```
function check_success {
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then 
        echo "success " >> $log
    else echo "failed" >> $log
    fi
}



ls && check_success

ls non-existant
check_success
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no really clean way to do that.  This is clean and might be good enough?

```
PS4='($?)[$LINENO]'
exec 2>>"$log"
```

That will show every command run in the log, and each entry will start with the exit code of the previous command...

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in `.bashrc` and call it whenever

```
function log_status { [ $? == 0 ] && echo success>>/tmp/status || echo fail>>/tmp/status }
```

If you want it after every command you could make the prompt write to the log (note the original PS1 value is appended).

```
export PS1="\$([ \$? == 0 ] && echo success>>/tmp/status || echo fail>>/tmp/status)$PS1"
```

(I'm not experienced with this, perhaps [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/) is a more appropriate place to put it)

Or even get more fancy and see the result with [colours](http://tartley.com/?p=657).

I guess you could also play with getting the last executed command:

- [How do I get "previous executed command" in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756360/how-do-i-get-previous-executed-command-in-a-bash-script)
- [Get name of last run program in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197441/get-name-of-last-run-program-in-bash)
- [BASH: echoing the last command run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run)